# Block incoming request when SSL verification is disabled

Tags: nginx, ssl, burp

I have my REST APIs configured to work over https using nginx( java APIs deployed in tomcat and nginx is configured for DNS mapping). Our testing team has managed to access the APIs using burp tool (I assume it allows them to access with SSL verification disabled) and they were able to alter the API response before the client receives it. My nginx server is configured to work on SSL with proxy forward setup for http to https. How can I block the API requests which has SSL verification disabled, so that I can stop them altering the response? Below is my nginx config.

```
    upstream mlljava{
            server 172.31.5.222:8090;
    }    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mllwebapi.xyz.in www.mllwebapi.xyz.in;
        underscores_in_headers      on;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        ssl_certificate     /home/ubuntu/175e9.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/key.key;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://mlljava/;
                proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the tomcat instance on the same machine? Can you post your relevant part of the `nginx.conf`?

Comment: @RobAudenaerde I have updated the nginx configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not (yet) familiar with this `upstream` configuration. It that the same box as the nginx is running on? Else you probably expose the 8090 port to the outside world, allowing plain HTTP request to be made there?

Comment: in my case it is running a different box and 8090 is open only within VPN and is accessible to the nginx via private IP. I'm still looking for an answer to my query.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no way to know on the server side if the client have SSL verification disabled. Also the client can just add your certificate to his authorize CAs and then he doesn't have to disable SSL verification

Answer (score 0):

Does adding this to server configuration helps?

```
# force https-redirects
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 401 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

[Configure Nginx SSL + force HTTP to redirect to HTTPS + force www to non-www on Serverpilot free plan (Using Nginx configuration file only)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/configure-nginx-ssl-force-http-to-redirect-to-https-force-www-to-non-www-on-serverpilot-free-plan-using-nginx-configuration-file-only)

[Nginx: force SSL on one path, non-SSL on others](https://serverfault.com/questions/270339/nginx-force-ssl-on-one-path-non-ssl-on-others)